# Finding Contraints Matrix in constrOptim (R)

Tags: r, optimization, continuous-integration, simulation

I would like to set the constraints for `constrOptim` to optimize the following function:

```
logistic<-function(b,x,target){
  b1<-b[1]
  b2<-b[2]
  log<-function(x){1/(1+exp(-(b1+b2*x)))}
  abs(mean(log(x))-target)
}
```

Optimization to `target=.75` can generally be done using

```
optim(c(1,1),logistic,x=data,target=.75,hessian=TRUE,method='SANN')
```

Method SANN seems necessary, as the function is not differentiable.

The constraint is that b2>0 (condition 1) or b2<0 (condition 2), while b1 can be any real number. But how can I extend this function to `constrOptim`? Specifically, I do not know how to specify arguments `ui` and `ci`.

Alternative approaches to optimization under these constraints also welcome. Thanks.

**EDIT**
I think that I found a workarround. We find constraint b2<0 by redefining `logistic` to

```
logistic_lt<-function(b,x,target){
  b1<-b[1]
  b2<-b[2]
  if(b2>0){b2<-b2*(-1)}
  log<-function(x){1/(1+exp(-(b1+b2*x)))}
  abs(mean(log(x))-target)
}
```

Still I'd be interested in a solution involving constrOptim.

Comment: Reading the help , I don't think you can do this using `constrOptim` since you use a sort of a logical constraint and non linear one ( imaginary == 0)

Comment: You can solve two separate problems, one with the `b2>0` constraint, one with the `b2<0` constraint, and take the best solution. To impose those constraints, you can reparametrize the problem, e.g., by replacing `b2` with `log(1+exp(b2))` (that is a logarithm, not your user-defined `log` function), which is always positive. `SANN` is probably not a good choice: it is the slowest optimization algorithm available -- if you minimize the square of the difference, instead of its absolute value, the other algorithms should give a correct result.